# XPATH: Different inputs for multiple elements with same xpath, based on value of parent element

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I have a relatively complex problem with xpath on Python. Here is my HTML layout:

```
<label name=A>
   <span name=B>
      "Your Salary"
<div name=C>
   <div name=D>
      <input name=E>

<label name=A>
   <span name=B>
      "Years of Experience"
<div name=C>
   <div name=D>
      <input name=E>
```

Because of the DOM, I can only ever estimate the name of input E. However, there may be multiple input Es which require different entries. My attempt was to find the title of the input at span B and base the different response inputs on that as shown here:

```
form_number = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "E")]')

for link in form_number:
    if driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "E")]/parent::div/parent::div/preceding-sibling::label/span[1][text()[contains(., "Salary")]]'):
        link.send_keys("55000")
    else: link.send_keys("2")
```

The idea here being if the question has anything to do with a "salary," to input "55000." For any other question I'll settle for "2," in this case being "2 years of experience." This seems to work for the first entry, however it will apply the key (in this case 55000) to all inputs, rather than just the first. It seems like Python isn't cycling through the "if - else" loop for each element, rather taking the first condition and pasting it for every element of the list. This is the closest that I have gotten thus far.

Thank you all so much for helping me as I cut my teeth on this API!

(Edit) So after playing around a bit more... it seems like this might be a problem with the API itself. Even if I submit the default value "2" for each input, and *then* run the function, it will still replace both inputs to 55000. Might have to work-around this by manually iterating through the list number?

Comment: Please share an actual example of your input XML rather than merely an outline or "sketch" of it. It's really not clear what the structure of your input XML is, which makes it difficult to offer any clear advice.

Comment: Since there are no closing tags it's hard to understand the relations between nodes. Please add valid HTML-code sample. Also simplify your question to something like *"I need to select `input` node that is descendant of `div name="C"` if its immediate preceding sibling `label` has text `"Years of Experience"` "*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take another approach to solve the issue.

First you identify the `parent tags` which is label and then use `try..except` block to check if element there then set the `inputbox` value else go to except block and set the other `inputbox` value.

```
#Fisrt identify the labels tag
parentTags=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//label[@name="A"]')

#Iterate the loop
for ptag in parentTags:

   try:
      #identify the tag text of the label, if found then set the input value as 55000
      ptag.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[conains(.,"Salary")]')
      ptag.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::div[1]//input').send_keys("55000")
   except:
      #Not found then set the input value as 2
      ptag.find_element_by_xpath('.//following-sibling::div[1]//input').send_keys("2")
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you so much! I was actually able to build on your foundation a bit by using multiple try loops with a True/False tag (False = everything else). Works like a charm. I really wonder why "if-else" doesn't function properly though. Was it something I did?

Comment: What is `find_elements_by_xpath` supposed to return? An array that might contain  elements or possibly be empty? It looks like you are treating it as a boolean expression; perhaps your `if` statement needs to check the size of the array, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if driver.find_elements_by_xpath ...` statement does not depend on the value of `link`; you will evaluate the exact same xpath once for each value of `link` in your loop. Presumably you should have something like `link.find_elements_by_xpath` (instead of `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`) in your `if` statement, in order to evaluate an xpath expression multiple times with a different context node each time (the different `input` elements which will appear as the sequential values of the `link` variable).

```py
form_number = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@name, "E")]')

for link in form_number:
    if link.find_elements_by_xpath('parent::div/parent::div/preceding-sibling::label/span[1][text()[contains(., "salary")]]'):
        link.send_keys("55000")
    else: link.send_keys("2")
```

Secondly, I wonder about the use of the `contains` function. This function tests to see if a particular string contains another string anywhere within it. e.g. `contains('abc', 'b')` returns true. You might just want to use the xpath `=` operator instead, to see if the string values are equal.

Note also that both the `contains` function and the `=` operator are  case sensitive, i.e. `contains("Your Salary", "salary")` equals false.

```py
form_number = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@name = "E"]')

for link in form_number:
    if link.find_elements_by_xpath('parent::div/parent::div/preceding-sibling::label/span[1][text()[contains(., "Salary")]]'):
        link.send_keys("55000")
    else: link.send_keys("2")
```

Comment: That was a really good idea! Sadly it seems even link.find_elements_by_xpath is returning the same value for both inputs. I was thinking of adding "break" after link.send_keys("55000"), however in my trial runs this did nothing but stop the entire process.

As for the contains function, the real-life DOM is so variable that I can't know any full name or id tag. And the capitalization issue was fortunately limited to this example, however I went ahead and changed that for future reference.

Comment: There may be an error in your XPath itself, but without seeing the actual XML data you're working with, it's impossible to be sure. Your existing sample is not well-formed XML; it's just a vague suggestion of the actual structure.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what XML is to be honest. I'll give it to you if I have it. The only thing I can supply is my original test code, which is the same logic but just busier. Any source code from the website I don't have direct access to. Best I can do is send you a photo. Doesn't seem to be an issue of identifying the elements though. That works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yeah I think your Python code is quite readable, but the HTML you've supplied doesn't look right. But if you can copy and paste the actual HTML code of the page (or at least, of a portion of the page that includes all the relevant parts), that would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect the latest code that you've tried (including the change to use `link.find_elements_by-xpath`, and the updated xpath itself (starting with `parent::div` etc)?

Comment: Maybe you want `preceding-sibling::label[1]` rather than just `preceding-sibling::label` in your XPath? You are only interested in the _immediately_ preceding label aren't you? Are there other preceding sibling `label` elements? Again, unless you post the actual HTML of the page, it's hard to know what the issue might be.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Conal! Again apologies, the XML was so dense I didn't think it was worth posting. I'm 90% sure it wasn't a problem with the xpaths, as my code was and is able to successfully locate everything. It looks like it was solved with using "try - except" loops instead of "if - else." Still not entire sure why this api isn't able to handle this logic, but the moral of the story is that you gotta be really careful with referencing the xpath array that selenium provides.